# jquery does not react on select/option change event

Tags: jquery, select, handler

Can someone please tell me where the mistake is, I just can't see it.
'e1 has changed' should be logged to the console when the select changes.

html:

```
<select name="e1" id="e1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
$('#e1').change(function() {
    console.log('e1 has changed');
});
```

jquery is definitely working since I'm successfully "getting" server data for other elements.

Comment: The code looks correct. Can you elaborate exactly what isn't working, or perhaps give a use case where this code doesnt work?

Comment: Code is correct, problem isn't in there. Can you explain further?

Comment: Your code does work (changed the console.log to an alert to make life easier here.) http://jsfiddle.net/NJskv/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code

```
$('#e1').change(function() {
    console.log('e1 has changed');
});
```

is likely not in your document ready handler, and is therefore being run before your dom element `e1` is ready.  You can create a document ready handler, which will run when your dom elements are ready, like this

```
$(function() {
    $('#e1').change(function() {
        console.log('e1 has changed');
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.  Here is the jsFiddle code -

http://jsfiddle.net/CC5P6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#e1').change(function() {
    alert('e1 has changed');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I you haven't done so already you should wrap your code in the `$(document).ready(`:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#e1').change(function() {
       console.log('e1 has changed');
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#e1').change(function() {
            console.log('e1 has changed');
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<select name="e1" id="e1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

document.ready is the key here, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

For select menus, the change event occurs when an option is selected by Keyboard and Mouse buttons events and NoScript effectively nterferes.
 For text fields or text areas, the change event occurs when the field loses focus.
 thus you can not use "change event"  directly (without   select  any option by Keyboard or Mouse)
  try this cod:

```
<select name="subpos" id="subpos">
<option value="examplel">examplel</option>
<option value="sample">sample</option>
<option value="fortest">fortest</option>
</select>


<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#subpos').change(function() {
            console.log('subpos has changed');
        }); 
        $("#subpos").val('sample');//combo box has change but dont appear in console log. why?
   });
</script>
```

after run ; see console log 
 you  can't see 'subpos has changed' in console log . but in action  'subpos has changed' 
what is happend? 
its should be logged to the console when the select changes .
now by selecting that option from the drop-down you can see cosole log is change